# Integral of a product involving of exponential of delta function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, dirac-delta

My question today is how do you integrate this for an arbitrary real, continuous and differentiable function $g(x)$ (with $g(+ \infty) = 0$ and $g(0) = 0$, $g(x) \geq 0$) and a real number $a_0 > 0$:

$ I_0 = \int_0^{+ \infty} d x g(x) e^{- a_0 x \delta(x-x_0)} $

And then, how do you integrate this one (also real numbers):

$ I_0 = \int_0^{+ \infty} d x g(x) e^{- \sum_p a_p x \delta(x-x_p)} $

Where $\delta(x)$ is the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function):

$\int \delta(x) f(x) dx = f(0)$

Thank you for reading

**Example for g**

For example we can have:

$$g(x) = x e^{-x} $$

**What I tried**

With *absolutely no mathematical rigor* (but Michael Penn is a genius for me + he knows how to backflip on flatground, I really like this guy), but this is how we sometimes discover something (this is an applied spectroscopy problem I had)! I tried a simplified integral (but this is almost the same):

$$ I = \int_0^{+ \infty} d x g(x) e^{- \delta(x-x_0)} $$

What do we have for $e^{- \delta(x-x_0)} $ ?

Simply:

$$ e^{- \delta(x-x_0)} = 0, \quad x = x_0 $$
$$ e^{- \delta(x-x_0)} = 1, \quad x \neq x_0 $$

This is like the "inverse" behavior of the Dirac delta. So let's try to integrate:

$$I = \int_0^{x_0^-} d x g(x) + \int_{x_0^-}^{x_0^+} 0 g(x) d x + \int_{x_0^+}^{+ \infty} d x g(x) $$

I propose 2 things:

We "pass to the limit" first proposition:

$$ I \stackrel{?}{=} \int_0^{+ \infty} d x g(x)  $$

or we "supress the $g(x_0)$ because not include in the interval" second proposition:

$$ I \stackrel{?}{=} \int_0^{+ \infty} d x g(x) - g(x_0)  $$

This seems really weird and certainly wrong but this is here to stimulate the motivation to answer to my question ^^.

Something that motivated me to use the second proposition is that when we do the Taylor expansion:

$$ I = \int_0^{+ \infty} d x g(x) \left( 1 - \delta(x-x_0) + \delta^2(x-x_0)/2 - ... \right)  $$

and we can integrate the first two terms to find again the second proposition,

$$ I = \int_0^{+ \infty} d x g(x) - g(x_0) + \int_0^{+ \infty} d x g(x) \left( \delta^2(x-x_0)/2 - ... \right)  $$

but I don't know how to do with the rest which seems to diverge...

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145239/discussion-on-question-by-fefetltl-integral-of-a-product-involving-of-exponentia); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: I'm not familiar with distributions, but I know about measure exponential; applying it to Dirac delta not focused at 0 gives something similar to Poisson distribution measure. Perhaps someone knowing better this topic could use this analogy, so I'm leaving it here

Comment: The discussion was really really interresting, it is unfortunate

Comment: Thanks, Poisson distrib, I will take à look on it

Comment: distributions aren't necessary for this problem since the e to the minus delta is a proper function on the reals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track.

$\int_0^\infty g(x)e^{-a_0x\delta(x-x_0)}dx =\int_0^{x_0-\epsilon}g(x)dx+\int_{x_0-\epsilon}^{x_0+\epsilon}g(x)e^{-a_0x\delta(x-x_0)}dx+\int_{x_0+\epsilon}^\infty g(x)dx$

$\int_{x_0-\epsilon}^{x_0+\epsilon}g(x)e^{-a_0x\delta(x-x_0)}dx\le \sup{(|g(x)|,|g(x_0)e^{-a_0x_0}}|) \cdot 2\epsilon$

So if $g(x)$ is bounded on the interval of integration for the middle integral, the limit of the integral as $\epsilon \to 0 $  is $0$.

Essentially this is integrating $g(x)$ with a jump discontinuity at $x_0$. Countably many jump discontinuities tend not to effect the value of the integral.

Comment: That is why we physicist need more mathématicians than other physicists... thanks, unfortunate that the $x_0$ does not appear in the result... but yeah $g$ is a smooth bounded function

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What happens to the value of an integral when you replace the integrand with 0 for countably many values? Notice how multiplying a negative exponential of delta is the identity function for all points except for a single one, $x_0$.

Comment: Propose Something,  I mean try to évaluate the integral

Comment: The only thing left is to determine what happens with your constant $a_0$, which will multiply the value through by a constant, which I will leave you to compute (it is very simple)

Comment: Let me know if you are struggling with the proof - This hint should bring you very close to the solution.

Comment: With the constant I would say it is the same no?

$$ \int_0^{+ \infty} d x g(x) e^{- a_0 \delta(x-x_0)} = \int_0^{+ \infty} d x g(x) $$ 

And for my purpose $a_0 > 0$

Comment: If the solution include the constant $a_0$ and $g(x_0)$ it should be very amazing for my results (we don't often encountered integrals like this in physics)

Comment: I put you one point by the way